# Django REST Framework: upload image and rename it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My application is used to register restaurants in the system. Along with some data (like restaurant name) the frontend is sending restaurant logo. Using this code:

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_error_messages['image_not_png'] = _(
            'Only .png files are supported.'
        )    

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')
            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)
            if file_extension is not 'png': 
                self.fail('image_not_png')
            complete_file_name = '%s.%s'.format(file_name, file_extension)
            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        return imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
```

I was able to decode and save the logo to the disk with some randomly generated name. Now I'm wondering how to name that file properly. By 'properly' I mean that I want to name the logo file the same as is the restaurant name, which is problematic, because `to_internal_value` doesn't have access to anything else than the file data The questions is: where should I put the code to rename the file to be the same as the restaurant name that came in the same request?

Comment: `complete_file_name = '%s.%s'.format(file_name, file_extension)` this is the line you are naming your file. Is that what you asked?

Comment: That's the place where I'm naming my file, but the name used is a UUID. What I want to do, is to name it in relation to the `Restaurant` object it belongs to. I can't do it in the `to_internal_value` method because it doesn't have access to the request.